# Unknown account error when initiating transactions from remote node

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, metamask, ropsten

I am using Ropsten network and trying to transfer ether from my metamask account to my another account using geth client. I am using the methods like **eth.signTransaction, eth.sendTransaction in CLI**, it returns **unknown account error**. Whether the initiating account should be available in the node or not ?